# Conflict of interest for phd external review

Tags: phd, thesis, peer-review, conflict-of-interest

If an external reviewer is invited to review phd thesis, will it be considered as (conflict of interest) if the reviewer was previously the applicant bachelor thesis supervisor?

Answer (score 4):

It is just something that should be revealed. If you are the student, then ask your current supervisor first. If you are the external person, just communicate that you have a prior relationship and its nature.

An external review isn't an adversarial role. It is an attempt to verify good work.

Attitudes matter, of course. If you had an attitude that you had to "bring down" the student at any cost, then it is a clear conflict. Erring on the opposite side is also possible. But that isn't normal or expected.

Answer (score 2):

Inform the people asking you of the possible conflict of interest and they can tell you their rules. In circumstances I’m familiar with, this scenario would not be a problem at all.